# How to insert data into Yii framework 2.0 CKEditor extension using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, yii2

I have installed CKEditor Yii framework 2.0 extension with the following command.

```
php composer.phar require "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget" "*"
```

I use it in my form with the following code.

```
use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor;

$form->field($myModel, 'text')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
    'options' => ['rows' => 6],
    'preset' => 'basic'
]);
```

Further more, I have a dropdownlist in my form. Let's assume as follows.

```
<select id="select-number" class="form-control" name="MyModel[select-number]">
    <option value="">-- Select a number --</option>
    <option value="1">Number 1</option>
</select>
```

When one selects an option, I want to insert some default data into the CKEditor textarea. How can I select the CKEditor textarea and insert data into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view file try following snippet:

```
<script>
$('#select-number').on('change', function(){
    var textareaID = "<?= '#' . Html::getInputId($model, 'your-attribute') ?>";
    var data = $(this).find(':selected').text(); //or any other source of data
    //here we place data into editor instance
    CKEDITOR.instances[textareaID].setData(data);
})
</script>
```

Comment: got error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined